# Able to display all activity but unable to only show activity for followed users. Undefined methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial to implement a follower system similar to Twitter's (railstutorial.org). For now, I want to use this follower system to only display activities of users followed by the user currently logged in. I'm able to display all activities in the system on the /activities page with no issue. The Activities controller code that works is as follows:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.all
  end
end
```

The index page for the Activities controller lists all of the posts made by all users. However, I want to edit the controller code to only display the activities of followed users. How can I do this? All my attempts lead to no method errors. Here are relevant items:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :title, :location, :aboutme, :works_attributes
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
  validates_uniqueness_of :first_name, :last_name, :email, :case_sensitive => false

  has_many :works, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :works

  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed

  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

   def full_name
    [first_name, last_name].join(" ")
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
  end
end
```

Relationship model:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id, :follower_id

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


def index
    @users = User.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
end
end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @user.posts.all
    @works = @user.works.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
   def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.all
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.all
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def posts
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @user.posts.all
    render 'show_post'
  end
end
```

Relationships controller

class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I've been stuck on this problem for way too long. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please feel free to ask questions if you need more information.

How can I edit the Activities controller so that it displays activity for followed users?

**EDIT: It works!!

Comment: Can you post your code for the Activity model? How do users and activities interact?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't have an Activity model. I completely forgot to mention that I'm using the public_activity gem to handle activities (https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about the public_activity gem, but here's what the documentation suggests you need to do:

1. [Set the "owner" attribute on your activities.](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity/wiki/%5BHow-to%5D-Set-the-Activity%27s-owner-to-current_user-by-default)
2. Filter the activities you display: `PublicActivity::Activity.where(owner_type: "User", owner_id: current_user.followed_users.map {|u| u.id}).all` (This is based on [this sample code.](https://github.com/pokonski/activity_blog/blob/master/app/controllers/activities_controller.rb#L14))